# d3.selection type check in IE

Tags: d3.js

How to check if a given object is a `d3` selection?

The following code prints `true` in Chrome and Firefox, but `false` in Internet Explorer:

```
console.log(d3.select(document.body) instanceof d3.selection)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update 2017-01-17

With the release of D3 **v4** this problem has vanished ([changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection)):

> Selections no longer subclass Array using [prototype chain injection](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_prototype_chain_injection); they are now plain objects, improving performance.

And the API [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection) explicitly state:

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection) d3.**selection**() [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/index.js#L38)
>
> *[…]* This function can also be used to test for selections (`instanceof d3.selection`)

Using the new version, the following code will actually evaluate to true in all browsers:

```
d3.select() instanceof d3.selection   // true in Chrome, FF, IE
```

For all those still on v3 the original answer below has an analysis and a workaround for the problem.

---

### Problem

Due to the inner workings of D3 every browser which supports [`Object.prototype.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) will print `true`, whereas browsers lacking support for `__proto__` will print `false`. Checking the [compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Browser_compatibility) it's obvious, that IE<11 will evaluate the expression to `false`. For this reason, you won't be able to use `instanceof d3.selection` to check for a D3 selection in IE<11. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/851) with D3, but it was closed and will not get fixed.

### Analysis

From D3's github repository:

1. **`selection/selection.js`**

Looking at the definition of [`d3.select()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/selection.js#L59-L69) which is the entry point of your call:

```
d3.select = function(node) {
  // ... removed for brevity

  return d3_selection([group]);
};
```

This will eventually return the result of the call to [`d3_selection()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/selection.js#L6-L9), which in turn will subclass `d3_selectionPrototype = d3.selection.prototype`.

```
function d3_selection(groups) {
  d3_subclass(groups, d3_selectionPrototype);
  return groups;
}
```

2. **`core/subclass.js`**

Finally, the implementation of [`d3_subclass()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/core/subclass.js) provides the answer to the problem:

```
var d3_subclass = {}.__proto__?

// Until ECMAScript supports array subclassing, prototype injection works well.
function(object, prototype) {
  object.__proto__ = prototype;
}:

// And if your browser doesn't support __proto__, we'll use direct extension.
function(object, prototype) {
  for (var property in prototype) object[property] = prototype[property];
};
```

It checks, if the browser supports `Object.prototype.__proto__` by checking for the existence of the `__proto__` accessor property on an empty object `{}`. If the browser supports it, D3 will directly assign the prototype, thus making it an instance of `d3.selection`. Otherwise, all properties of the prototype will be copied over to the object to be returned without explicitely setting the prototype. In this case your expression will evaluate to `false`.

### Workaround

Because [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_selection) is provided as a means to extend the selection's functionality you could implement a workaround by adding a new property to `d3.selection` which will, as was explained above, be made accessible by any selection, wether by prototyping or by copying properties.

```
// Include this at the start of your script to include the
// property in any selection created afterwards.
d3.selection.prototype.isD3Selection = true;

console.log(d3.select(document.body).isD3Selection);   // true in any browser
```