# Canonical way to see if a DOM element is wrapped in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently writing some library code and it's a common occurrence that a user could pass into a method either a bare DOM element, or an element that's been wrapped in d3, e.g. `var x = d3.select('#myRect');`

If the element has been wrapped in d3 then inside of my method i don't need to do 
`d3.select(x)` again.  If it's a bare DOM element, then I do.  My current method if tackling this is: `rect = rect.node ? rect.node() : rect;`

Is there a more canonical/proper way to check if a variable is wrapped in d3?

Comment: There should be a standard practice of including a `libraryId()` method in objects created by a library. That way you could check where the object came from, a la `if (myObject.libraryid() === "d3")`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232439/d3-selection-type-check-in-ie