# Identify given array is a d3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I identify that the given array is a d3 selection.
I have tried this

```
function Chart(container, data) {
    var isd3Selection = container instanceof Array && typeof container.node === 'function';
    this.container = isd3Selection ? container.node() : container;

    this.data = data;
    this.init();
}
```

Is there any other way to find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of D3 you might use one of the following:

#### v3

As laid out in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33236441/4235784) to [*"d3.selection type check in IE"*](http://[*%22d3.selection%20type%20check%20in%20IE%22*](/q/33232439)) this requires a little workaround. Because [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_selection) is provided as a means to extend the selection's functionality you could add a new property to `d3.selection` which will be made accessible by any selection, wether by prototyping or by copying properties.

```
// Include this at the start of your script to include the
// property in any selection created afterwards.
d3.selection.prototype.isD3Selection = true;

d3.select(document.body).isD3Selection;   // true
```

#### v4

As of v4 a selection is not just a nested array any more but a JavaScript object, which will make life even more simple. You can use the standard [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property to check for a D3 selection:

```
d3.select(document.body).constructor.name === "Selection"   // true
```

Note, that this will only work when using the unminified version of D3 as pointed out by O. R. Mapper in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845237/identify-given-array-is-a-d3-selection#comment74647879_39847179). For v4 the preferred solution should be using the `instanceof` operator as was laid out in thedude's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804518/4235784).

Comment: This does not work reliably. In my project, `d3.select(document.body).constructor.name` currently returns `'zi'` - probably because our code gets minified before deployment.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The result is the same.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: No, it's not. `d3.select(document.body).constructor.name === "Selection"` returns `false` for me.

Comment: You didn't understand: as you're using the minified version, test for `"zi"`. It's the same **principle**, that's what I meant.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It's a hack, though! For v4 the preferred solution should use `instanceof` as pointed out in thedude's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43804518/4235784).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: I'm not sure *you* understand: The next time the minifer runs, the name `Selection` might be replaced with anything else. There is no guarantee it is always `'zi'`.

Answer (score 4):

V4 way to do this:

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection)

> d3.selection()
>
> Selects the root element, document.documentElement. This function can also be used to test for selections (instanceof d3.selection) or to extend the selection prototype. For example, to add a method to check checkboxes:

You can test it like this:

```
d3.select(document.body) instanceof d3.selection // true
```