# Determine whether an object is a D3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is a safe way to determine whether a given JavaScript object is a D3 selection?

The constructor name in the prototype does not appear to be something that external code should rely upon (`zi` in the version I am using ... possibly due to minification). Therefore, the currently accepted solution for [more or less the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845237/identify-given-array-is-a-d3-selection) does not work for me.

I could make an educated guess based upon checking for a couple of members, but is there any clean and safe way to do this that does *not* rely on the constructor name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify given array is a d3 selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845237/identify-given-array-is-a-d3-selection)

Comment: @altocumulus: I agree this is a duplicate of the other question - didn't pick the right search terms to find that other question. Unfortunately, the other question does not provide a usable solution :-/

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I've posted to the original as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In v4 you could do this:

```
obj instanceof d3.selection
```